# Why do the following two pieces of code run so differently？

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, v8

Look at these two pieces of code, the second only add the third line. But time is 84 times. Anybody can explain why?

[image: foo]
[image: bar]

```js
let LIMIT = 9999999;
let arr = new Array(LIMIT);
// arr.push(1);
console.time('Array insertion time');
for (let i = 1; i < LIMIT; i++) {
  arr[i] = i;
}
console.timeEnd('Array insertion time');
```

```js
let LIMIT = 9999999;
let arr = new Array(LIMIT);
arr.push(1);
console.time('Array insertion time');
for (let i = 1; i < LIMIT; i++) {
  arr[i] = i;
}
console.timeEnd('Array insertion time');
```

Comment: Post code, not pictures of code

Comment: I see no code and no pictures

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12327958/why-are-these-javascript-for-loops-significantly-slower-on-firefox-then-chrome

Answer (score 1):

The `arr.push(1)` operation creates a "sparse" array: it has a single element present at index `9999999`. V8 switches the internal representation of such a sparse array to "dictionary mode", i.e. the array's backing store is an index→element dictionary, because that's significantly more memory efficient than allocating space for 10 million elements when only one of them is used.

The flip side is that accessing (reading or writing) elements of a dictionary-mode array is slower than for arrays in "fast/dense mode": every access has to compute the right dictionary index, and (in the scenario at hand) the dictionary has to be grown several times, which means copying all existing elements to a new backing store.

As the array is filled up, V8 notices that it's getting denser, and at some point transitions it back to "fast/dense mode". By then, most of the slowdown has already been observed. The remainder of the loop has some increased cost as well though, because by this time, the `arr[i] = i;` store has seen two types of arrays (dictionary mode and dense mode), so on every iteration it must detect which state the array is in now and handle it accordingly, which (unsurprisingly) costs more time than not having to make that decision.

Generalized conclusion: with JavaScript being as dynamic and flexible as it is, engines can behave quite differently for very similar-looking pieces of code; for example because the engine optimizes one case for memory consumption and the other for execution speed, or because one of the cases lets it use some shortcut that's not applicable for the other (for whatever reason). The good news is that in many cases, correct and understandable/intuitive/simple code also tends to run quite well (in this example, the stray `arr.push` looks a lot like a bug).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I learned a lot. If I replace arr.push(1) to arr[LIMIT] = 1, the code runs slow. But if I relace it to arr[LIMIT - 1] = 1, the array seems also "sparse" array，but it runs fast. Can you help explain this? Looking forward to your answers.

Comment: `arr[LIMIT-1] = 1` can use the existing, preallocated backing store, so it doesn't trigger the switch to dictionary mode.

Comment: When an answer has answered your question, the StackOverflow way of expressing appreciation is to mark it as accepted, and optionally upvote it :-)